# How can I access a JAX-RS resource?

Tags: jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I've created a simple JAX-RS resource class for my Java EE based project. I am trying to get a response back from the server but when I access my url I get an error back. This is the class that I wrote:

```
@Path("/rest")
public class RestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String create(String name)
    {
        return "print my string";
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Do I have to define a new servlet in my web.xml? Is there something wrong with my current one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <display-name>crud-app</display-name>

    <!-- Activate the JSF 2.0 servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Tell the context which URLs to send through JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- This is an optional parameter, but it makes troubleshooting errors 
        much easier -->
    <!-- You are advised to remove this context parameter before a production 
        deployment -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>person.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/ui/error/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/ui/error/viewExpired.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are you deploying this to? Is it an enterprise container or just servlet container like tomcat?

Comment: I am deploying it to a wildfly server. I managed to fix my problem by using resteasy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by using RESTEasy. Here is my updated web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <display-name>crud-app</display-name>

    <!-- Activate the JSF 2.0 servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Tell the context which URLs to send through JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- This is an optional parameter, but it makes troubleshooting errors 
        much easier -->
    <!-- You are advised to remove this context parameter before a production 
        deployment -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>person.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/ui/error/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/ui/error/viewExpired.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```